# add pdf file to a jeditorpane in swing java

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am trying to open pdf file in jeditorPane its opening the pdf page but not in the actual format but in binary format .Is it possible to open pdf file in jeditorpane or jtextpane.
I am using the following code.

```
 try
 {
  JEditorPane pane1= new JEditorPane();
  File f1= new File("path of the pdf file");
  pane1.setPage(f1.toURL());
 }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }
```

Comment: From what I recall JEditorPane doesn't support PDF...

Comment: then how can be open pdf file in java swing jframe form

Comment: Try a Google search for "java swing PDF viewer", I saw mention of two open source projects listed in the top 5 return results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JEditorPane does not support PDF format by default. If you implement the appropriate `EditorKit`, you could make it work but I believe this would be a very tedious work to perform.

However it seems that Adobe has provided a Java bean PDF viewer that you could probably integrate in your application to display a PDF. Have a look at [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/10/20/accessing-pdf-with-acrobat-viewer-javabean.html).

Comment: i think he doesn't want to show the PDF in a formatted way, he wants to see the binary data.

Comment: @kutschkem I believe you misread the question. He actually tried to set the PDF file as the source of the JEditorPane but the JEditorPane did not render it as a PDF but as binary data. He actually wants to see a PDF in a formatted way. Re-read the equestion, you will see that it is obviously what he is looking for.

Comment: Pdf viewer is just asking to accept the license agreement but not showing the PDF file in viewer

Comment: @user1960524 I can't really help you with such comment. No code, no stacktraces, not much information I can get to guess what the problem is. Post another question on SO with your current code to see if anyone can help you (I am willing to follow up a new question from you on that matter).